# Echo new line in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';
    $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
    $arr = explode('+', $q);

    foreach($arr as $ing)
    {
        echo $ing;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Calling:

```
findByIncredients.php?q=Hans+Wurst+Wurstel
```

Source code HTML:

```
Hans Wurst Wurstel<br/>
```

Why is there only one newline?

Comment: please use print_r($arr);  Display array here

Comment: Explode using space, not `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+s in URL are urlencoded spaces. So what php sees in the variable is "Hans Wurst Wurstel". You need to split by space ' ', not +

```
arr = explode (' ',$q);
```

Answer (score 1):

"+" gets converted to SPACE on URL decoding.
You may want to pass your string as str1-str2-str3 in get parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
$arr = explode (' ',$q);

foreach($arr as $ing)
{
echo $ing;
echo "<br/>";
}

mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hans+Wurst+Wurstel` is the url escaped query string. The php page will likely process it once unescaped (in this case, all `+`s will be translated into spaces). You should choose a delimiter for `explode` according to the string as it is in that moment. You can use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for a raw print if you don't know how the string (or any kind of variable) looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. While the standard RFC 3986 url encoding would encode the space " " as "%20", due to historical reasons, it can also be encoded as "+". When PHP parses the query string, it will convert the "+" character to a space.

This is also illustrated by the existence of both:

- [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode): equivalent of what PHP uses internally, will convert " " to "+".
- [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode): RFC-conformant encoder, will convert " " to "%20".

I'm assuming you want to `explode` by space. If you really wanted to encode a "+" character, you could use "%2B", which is the `rawurlencode` version and will always work.

(EDIT)

Related questions:

- [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)
- [PHP - Plus sign with GET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671840/php-plus-sign-with-get-query)