# How to receive special character?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sending below data from textarea:

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
?>
```

But when I get the data from the client on server it becomes like below. It escapes the  `++`

sign which is special character.

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
?>
```

How to get data as it is sent?

Comment: Why are you appending to the same file straight after appending to it once?

Comment: Bro i am appending the file in the format like code : and after that recieved code

Comment: There's nothing in this code that shows what is alerted (what data is sent back to the ajax). Are you alerting "The number is: $x The number is: $x The number is: $x"?

Comment: If the php is _as is_ inside the textarea it would be a string, and therefore won't execute but treated as such. It seems like yours is the expected behaviour: you send a string code, you get a string code

Comment: What's wrong with this? `file_put_contents($myfile,"code: ".$code."\n",FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: I am just saying that i want to send the for loop like <?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
?>but it received as <?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
?> ignore the other part

Comment: your question is not clear at all..

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your problem; show us your form.

Comment: you can see form here - http://web.guru99.com/ the code editor on web.guru99.com is my text area if i am insert for loop there then it escape ++ sign so it goes to infinite loop

Comment: ++ is not special in any way. Do you have code on the server which processes the posted code before it is executed? Please post that.

Comment: you Can take  POST method & var params = { code: code };

Comment: @WolfgangStengel Not quite true.  A plus symbol dictates a space for GET requests.

Comment: @SanjayRathod See my answer for why that is.

Comment: @Daedalus Right. I was assuming he would let a regular form post it. Nice catch with very few information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [++ sign gets skipped. How to tackle this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439017/sign-gets-skipped-how-to-tackle-this)

Answer (score 1):

Submitting raw input with a plus sign via HTTP GET will cause the plus sign to not be sent. It is a reserved character. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671840/php-plus-sign-with-get-query)

Your old code built the GET request by hand like so:

```
var code = "code=" + code;
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: code,
  /// ...
});
```

But you never used `encodeURIComponent(code)`, thus causing your plus signs to be lost to the gaping jaws of the specification.

```
var code = "code=" + encodeURIComponent(code);
```

jQuery will do this automatically though if you pass it a plain object. Building urls is annoying, so this is the pattern I prefer:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: {
    code: code
  },
  /// ...
});
```

Comment: Yours is the better answer, so, +1.

Comment: Sorry that I "stole" your answer :*) Yours didn't appear for me until right after I posted mine.

Comment: It was deleted as I was unable to replicate the problem, until I fixed a few variables in the first bit of code given.  So no harm there.

Answer (score 0):

With no comments on the rest of your code, you are executing a GET request..  For url encoding, a `+` sign is equal to a space.  But if you want to retain those plus signs(`+`) upon the submission of the data.. you must url encode the string.  There is a function for this, [`encodeURIComponent(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  I would suggest you use that.  That aside, be careful what you evaluate php wise.

Normally, the form would take care of this for you, but since you are circumventing that action, this is one of the fixes.