# Decrypted algorithm just sometimes works

Tags: php, encryption

I want to encrypt an email to decrypt later.

At that point I don't care about safety, I just want it working. The mail is stored in `$umail`

Researching **stackoverflow** I found the following code which I have adapted:

```
 $keyword = "Key";
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
 $activation = base64_encode($iv.mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash('sha256', $keyword, true), $umail, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
 $activation = rawurlencode($activation);
```

$activation is the encrypted mail.

I get the encrypted mail ($activation) as a part of a URL.

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
$key = rawurldecode($key);
$keyword = "Key";
$requestMail = base64_decode($key);
$ivDec = substr($requestMail, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash('sha256', $keyword, true), substr($requestMail, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $ivDec), "\0");
```

Sometimes it shows the email I enter. Other times, with the same email input, it shows strange symbols when the encrypted word has "+".

Any advice?

It's solved. This is the post I needed:

[PHP - Plus sign with GET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671840/php-plus-sign-with-get-query)

I noticed that when a + was generated, decrypt was broken. In that post is explained how + is a PHP reserved word, so it must be converted to %2B and after that, reconverted to +. To do this you use: rawurlencode, rawurldecode.

Code is updated.

Enjoy!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string

Comment: With the "+" I mean that if my mail y userMail, and the encrypted word has a "+", the dencryption has strange symbols

Comment: *"(...) strange symbols when the encrypted word has '+'"*
Are you url encoding your messages before transmission?

Comment: I solved it @jDo, check the edited question

Comment: @Good. FYI the plus sign `+` is not a reserved keyword in PHP but in the [URI standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2)  created by the IETF. In other words, it would fail in all programming languages without the proper encoding.

Comment: @jDo oh thanks for the information